# What to do with residence permit when leaving definitely

Tags: resident-permit, morocco

I currently hold a 10 year residence permit which is still valid for 5 years. 
I am planning to leave Morocco next summer. By leaving I mean stop being a resident and going back to my country. I'll keep going to Morocco as a tourist for less than 3 months periods.

Shall I declare that I am leaving and won't be a resident anymore ?

Answer (score 1):

Some countries invalidate a residence permit when they learn that a person has left without the intention of returning.

So informing them of that intention simplifies that process.

Since you also intend to return as a visitor, doing this would avoid any confusion that they may think you are returning as a resident.